# How do I find the interior, closure and boundary of an arbitrary set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, geometric-topology

I'd like to find the interior, boundary, closure, etc. of an arbitrary set. I mean, if I'm working on a subset of $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}^2,$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$ it could be quite easy using Geogebra, but in other cases or sets that are complex to graph, it turns out to be very difficult.

So I'm asking about an algebraic method (most specifically, an example to understand) to find those sets.

Like $A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:0<(x-2)^2+y^2<1\}\cup\left\{\left(\dfrac{1}{n}+2,0\right):n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$

Comment: This set A is easy to draw. Hint: a circle and an interval.

Comment: Well in general, I'm not sure that the answer should be simple. The example you gave is still relatively simple, as $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a very nice topological space. Like how a closure of a finite union is the union of the closures.

Comment: I know, but what i want it's to do it algebraically getting the same result to understand how to proceed in other sets.

Comment: Well first of, maybe you should clarify what are you looking for exactly. I do not think you can 'algebraically" decide the closure or interior generally, do you have some more information?

Comment: I mean, i have the definition for all of those sets, for example int$(A)=\{x_0\in X:\exists r>0|B(x_0,r)\subset A\}$ and setting $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ and A with the set above. There's some algebraic method to do it with the definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, there is no procedure for finding the interior, boundary, and closure of a set, even in $\mathbb{R}^2$. As an example of some weirdness you could encounter, consider the set
$$
S= \Big\{ \Big(x,\sin\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big) \Big) \colon x > 0 \Big\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2.
$$
Then for each value $z \in [-1,1]$ we can find infinitely many distinct terms $0 < x_n < 1$ such that $\sin(\frac{1}{x_n}) = z$. It follows that the sequence $(x_n, \sin(\frac{1}{x_n}))$ converges to $(0,z) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Since $(0,z)$ is a limit point of $S$, by definition $(0,z)$ is in the boundary of $S$ for all $z \in [-1,1]$. You wouldn't necessarily guess that by looking at the formula for $S$.

Of course it's possible to construct even more pathological examples where the boundary is even harder to determine. See for example the [Mandelbrot set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set).

Edit: Just to throw in another weird example the [Sierpiński Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_triangle) is a closed set with empty interior. It is therefore equal to its own boundary.

Answer (score 0):

You have to develop intuition about what it means to be a limit point, on the boundary, etc. Sometimes looking at a graph is helpful. Here's a sketch of the set. Note that all but one of the sequence of points converging to $(2, 0)$ are already in the open punctured disk, so the set could be described more simply as:
$$
A = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: 0 <(x-2)^2 + y^2 < 1 \} \cup \{ (3, 0) \}.
$$
Here's a sketch, where I've indicated the sequence of points so you can see them:

[![A set of points in the plane][1]][1]

---

To answer your questions, the algebraic inequalities used in defining the sets allow you to rigorously confirm the following conclusions:

1. The interior of the set consists of all points who have an open neighborhood (e.g. a disk of arbitrarily small size) around them in $A$. This is just the punctured disk:
   $$
   A^\circ = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: 0 <(x-2)^2 + y^2 < 1 \} 
   $$
2. The closure includes the set and all of its limit points. The limit points are not necessarily in the set, but any neighborhood around a limit point intersects the set. You get the center of the disk and the circle of points at the boundary of the disk:
   $$
   \overline{A\,} = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: (x-2)^2 + y^2 \leq 1 \}
   $$
3. The boundary consists of all points who have a neighborhood that intersects both the set and its complement, or equivalently the closure with the interior removed. This consists of the center of the disk and the circle:
   $$
   \partial A = \{ (2,0) \} \cup \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: (x-2)^2 + y^2 = 1 \}
   $$
   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLWXH.png

Comment: And how i generalize that on more dimension, like an hypersphere on 5d or 6d, or on sets like e^x=sin(y)? I'm sorry if I'm so annoying

Comment: I feel like you're searching for a general procedure where one doesn't exist.

Comment: Ah, it doesn't exists..